# SSRS Data-Driven Subscription: Character Limit on To: Field for Emails

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, subscription

I've started using Data-driven subscriptions in SSRS lately and have come across a weird issue that I'm having a hard time finding information on. I'm worried there is a possibly a character limit on how big the "To:" field can be for emails.

I set up a Data-driven subscription that was supposed to email ~30 recipients.  The Subscription ran and according the log it was successful ("Done: 1 processed of 1 total; 0 errors.") --except nobody got the email.

I have Standard subscriptions that email this many recipients with no issue.

If I change the Data-driven subscription to only email one individual, it works fine.

If I change the Data-driven subscription to email a distribution list (that contains 30 recipients)--same problem as before, it doesn't work.

From what I understand, the message in the web-based log about "0 errors" only indicates that SSRS sent the message to Exchange for processing.  I could put a garbage email in there and the Subscription would still run and say ("0 errors").

My best guess is that there is some sort of character limit I'm bumping up against for Data-driven subscriptions specifically--but if that was true, I don't know why emailing the Distribution List doesn't work.

Does anyone have any ideas?  If this is a character limit issue, is there anywhere that the setting can be changed?  Thank you...

Comment: Were all 30 recipients on the same domain? Have you traced the mail messages through to their intended destination(s)? You could be fighting local policy configuration of the receiving SMTP mail server(s) which often impose limits on the number of recipients/message... and may just be silently dropping them on the /dev/null floor.

Comment: All 30 recipients are on the same domain, yes. I'm not sure how I would trace the message.  I suppose I could try contacting an Exchange or Systems admin in the organization, but once again I'm confused because I'm able to send messages to well over 30 recipients using Standard subscriptions.  Just (apparently) not Data-driven ones.